# Exercise books for self-study

Tags: self-learning, book-recommendation

I have been self-studying mathematics for many years now and I've noticed that you don't really find mathematics books which have solutions to the exercises, and sometimes they don't have exercises at all. I think that if I could do exercises and compare my answers to the solutions, it would give me much stronger understanding of the subjects.

So I was wondering if there is a book that would contain problems from different subjects in mathematics with solutions. I know there are some such books but they're usually concentrated on only one or two subjects. It would be convenient if all the exercises were in one book.

I'm looking for a book in the undergraduate level which would cover as wide range of fields in pure mathematics. Areas I'm interested in are analysis, algebra, topology and number theory. I'm excluding fields such as geometry, elementary algebra and other fields that are a subject of competition mathematics (IMO) because there are already a lot of resources for those.

If such a book existed, it would be a very valuable resource for self-study. Thanks!

---

Edit:

This question was put on hold as too broad. The reason, why I think it's better not to restrict this question too much, is because I know there aren't many such books, that I've described above, if any. This way the people answering have more freedom to suggest anything close to what I'm looking for. And because there aren't many such books, there won't be a problem of having too many possible answers.

Also, when I don't restrict it too much, I think more people could benefit from the question and answers.

According to help center: "if your question - - has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad" I don't think that this is the case with my question since the correct answer is the book with questions from as many fields as possible (and I did restrict it to fields mentioned above...).

Comment: mathematics is like infinity.You should mention the topic atleast !

Comment: In [Introduction to Smooth Manifolds](https://thunv.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/graduate-texts-in-mathematics-vol-218-john-m-lee-introduction-to-smooth-manifolds-springer-2013.pdf), Lee says "I have deliberately not provided written solutions to any of the problems, either
in the back of the book or on the Internet. In my experience, if written solutions
to problems are available, even the most conscientious students find it very hard
to resist the temptation to look at the solutions as soon as they get stuck. ... "

Comment: " ... But it is
exactly at that stage of being stuck that students learn most effectively, by struggling
to get unstuck and eventually finding a path through the thicket. Reading someone
else’s solution too early can give one a comforting, but ultimately misleading, sense
of understanding. [...] Even if someone else gives you a suggestion that turns out
to be the key to getting unstuck, you will still learn much more from absorbing the
suggestion and working out the details on your own than you would from reading
someone else’s polished proof.  "

Comment: @Jo Yeah, I get that. But the problem is that I'm not always sure if my solution is correct or efficient. I don't have a teacher who could check my answers or give help...

Comment: @laura Umm... I'm basically interested in everything taught in undergraduate level in pure mathematics. Algebra, topology, analysis, discrete mathematics...

Comment: @JoBe Let's make it survival of the fittest then

Comment: @Miksu that's you can always post your question here on math.stackexchange under the tag 'proof-verification' if you are not sure about your work

Comment: The book _Berkeley Problems in Mathematics_ contains several Cal prelim problems and solutions in a wide range of topics one should be proficient in by the first year of grad school.

Comment: Maybe the Schaum's Outline series.

Comment: @JoBe I do not think it is unreasonable to want a book with solutions - especially when self-studying, when there is no one to present problems or correct your work.  Working problems without getting any kind of feedback on your solution could lead to an overestimate of your mastery of the material.

Comment: I don't usually vote to close for "too broad." If you had narrowed down just a tiny bit (e.g., geometry, number theory) I might have abstained or even voted to leave open. Regardless, I think the only way for the book you describe to exist is for you to write it yourself.

Comment: @RobertSoupe In my defence, I'm aware that such a book might not exist and I'm trying to provide more freedom to those who answer to suggest anything close to what I'm asking by not limitimg the question too much. But if it would be better to limit, I'll try to do that.

Comment: @BenWest your comment might be what I'm looking for. If you could write it as answers, I might accept it!

Comment: @DougSpoonwood your comment might be what I'm looking for. If you could write it as answers, I might accept it!

Answer (score 3):

Miksu, hello!

I'm not able to recommend a single book covering both algebra and analysis, at least in English. Also, from your question it appears you're at a level where you're still becoming accustomed to rigorous math, and what does or doesn't constitute a proof. Therefore the books I'm going to suggest are at a level generally somewhat below that of, say, Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.

1. The solutions manual to Spivak's *Calculus*. (The problem statements are in the textbook.)
2. Demidovich. *Problems in Mathematical Analysis*.
3. Halmos. *Linear Algebra Problem Book*.
4. Faddeev, Sominsky. *Problems in Higher Algebra*.

The last two books have a separate "Hints" section that comes before the answers.